# How to load data from variable into django paginator?

Tags: django

I need to create paginator based on data from variable. Variable is just python lists.

views.py:

```
def test(request):

   db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",  # your host, usually localhost
                        user="pc",  # your username
                        passwd="3346378",  # your password
                        db="mc")

   cur = db.cursor()

   cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM hello left join hell on hello.Id=hell.Id ''')

   row = cur.fetchall()
```

So, row is lot's of lists. And how can I load it into paginator?
Or one way is to create table and model for data and work with it using Django ORM or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has built in `Paginator` class you can check this out: [paginator objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#paginator-objects) and a few examples here: [Pagination examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#module-django.core.paginator), to use in a view : [Using Pagination in view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view)

if it is referencing muliple objects then write plural variable names: so it is `rows` instead of `row`

So in your case in the view:

```
paginator = Paginator(rows, 25) # Show 25 rows per page
page = request.GET.get('page')
rows = paginator.get_page(page)
return render(request, 'example.html', {'rows': rows})
```

And in HTML:

```
{% for r in rows %}

    {{ r }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if rows.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ rows.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ rows.number }} of {{ rows.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if rows.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ rows.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ rows.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but from this doc - I can't create paginator without setting data model in models?

Comment: @Jane I guess you can pass any list of data, just try it out